# how to use erb filter in nanoc compilation?

Tags: ruby, erb, nanoc

I begun to use `nanoc` recently and got some problems using `erb` filter. I put following code in `content/blogs.html`.

```
<ul>
  <% for item in articles() %>
  <li><%= item[:title] %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

and filter the item using `:erb` (in `Rules`)

```
compile '/blogs/' do
    filter :karmdown
    filter :erb
    layout 'default'
end
```

However, it does not work -- embedded Ruby got displayed without rendering. If I put above `ERB` in `layout`, it works fine. But it's not `filter` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure it's a quirk. I found the answer in practice.

Change following `compile rule` in `Rules`

```
filter :kramdown
filter :erb
```

to (reversely):

```
filter :erb
filter :kramdown
```

and it works fine.